# VBA Placing a Picture relative to a text box

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel spreadsheet that takes data from the first sheet and uses it to create a diagram. On this diagram it shows a picture above each text box it creates. The diagram it creates is based off a template where the picture is actually a empty text box with a picture background. This is the code which changes the background picture:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(s_picFrame)).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .UserPicture s_imageFile
    .TextureTile = msoFalse
End With
```

However the problem with this code is that the pictures inserted are very low quality, and resized/distorted to fit inside the original box.

Attempting to fix this problem I tried to import the pictures, but when I do this the pictures require a absolute position to be set. This doesn't work because often the pictures and text boxes need to be moved because of the amount of information in the textbox above.

This is the code I use to import the pictures:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=s_imageFile, linktofile:=msoFalse, _ 
savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=-1, Height:=-1
```

Is there a way I can change either of these pieces of code to either not distort the image I'm trying to place, or to place the image above a text box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change shape Left:=0, Top:=0 properties to be relative to the text box position properties.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=s_imageFile,  linktofile:=msoFalse, _ 
savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=" & txtbox.left & ", _
Top:=" & txtbox1.top + txtbox.height & ", Width:=-1, Height:=-1
```

Comment: Which textbox would this refer to? does txtbox refer to a selected one, or by the name of a textbox?

Comment: That would be the name of the text box that you want the picture to be located relative to.  So if the text box that is created is named textbox91 then you would refer to it as textbox91.lelft

Comment: For some reason when I run this code it doesn't insert any picture. Is there something I should be changing in this code other than the textbox name to make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure. It is the same code you had above just with the top and left properties changed.  you would have to post you code to allow the community to debug it.